# Force a C program to run in kernel mode for a while

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I wanted to test out something when the process is in kernel mode. A period of 10-15 seconds completely in kernel mode should be enough.

Is there any way to force a program written in C to run in kernel mode for a while? Would a single `read` system call on a huge buffer do?

Comment: I don't know what your definition of "running" in kernel mode is, but you might get what you want by just calling sleep()

Comment: Your idea with read will work. But it is unclear what are you trying to achieve by this...

Comment: You need a kernel module. A Hello World is very simple to do.

Comment: Well, you SHOULD NOT do the following unless you are a bad guy but... by abusing a bug in the operating system (kernel), you can sometimes manage to execute a piece of code with kernel privileges. Example of such an error (on Windows platform, fixed in May 2015): https://github.com/hfiref0x/CVE-2015-1701

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force running program to run in kernel mode.
In kernel mode there are more privileges available. It means that
program could execute special instructions that it cannot execute in 
user mode.
Obviously, there are no way, AFAIK, to force program in user mode to 
switch to kernel mode, because it compromises security: imagine,
that every process on will could switch to user mode, malicious
code can cause disaster by altering page tables, changing CPU settings, turning off interrupts and so on.

The only valid way of "switching" to kernel mode is executing system call.
That will cause trap to the kernel and after some kernel code is executed
control will return back to user code. However, I think that is not what you
asked about.

Comment: Not sure this is correct. What I ended up doing is -

Comment: 1. write a kernel module which does msleep; 2. write a C program to load this kernel module

Comment: What system do you use? On my Linux box there is no msleep(in man pages).

Comment: It's a kernel API available in linux/delay.h. You would need to install kernel-devel package and write it in kernel module.

Comment: What is the purpose of running program in kernel mode? Maybe there is alternatives needing only user-mode? I think it may be helpful/interesting to others too.